# Animating the linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am implementing the listview with one image and framelayout(conatining button and linearLayout) , I want to animate the linearLayout on click of image. Is it possible? I have written following code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="2dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/a"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_user_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Please help me.

Comment: which type of animation you want to do ?

Comment: yes it is possible i did the same on click of a image i animated the layout.Create `anim` folder in the resource add `anim` file if u don't want to do it programaticaly and then just use::`MyAnimation=AnimAnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ll1.getContext(),R.anim.stack_push);`
and on the click of image use 
`ll1.startAnimation(MyAnimation);`

Answer (score 0):

You can call animate method in onClickListener of imageview like..

```
ivmg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    startLayoutAnimation(myLayout);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

And define method as...

```
public void startLayoutAnimation(LinearLayout mLayout)
        {
            System.out.println("Inside startAnimation()");
            Animation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(0, 2, 0, 2);
            scaleAnim.setDuration(5000);
            scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
            scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            scaleAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        /*  Animation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360);
            rotateAnim.setDuration(5000);
            rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
            rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            rotateAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);*/

            Animation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF);
            rotateAnim.setDuration(5000);
            rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
            rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            rotateAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

            AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
            animationSet.addAnimation(scaleAnim);
            animationSet.addAnimation(rotateAnim);

            mLayout.startAnimation(animationSet);
        }
   }
```

I haven't tried animating layout yet. So you will have to check whether its working or not. Hope it helps